# Can everything in maths be proved from first principles?

Tags: logic

Can you prove every notion and concept in maths from first principles?

Comment: What are those "first principles"? Do you have any idea? :) Anyway, this is a perfectly philosophical question; it doesn't belong to this site.

Comment: How is this not about math?

Comment: Andrej Bauer has some comments in these matters that I find are very appropriate. Essentially, you could consider this a nice fiction or at best a heuristic guiding principle. Of course, others may have a different take.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo. any pointers for interested perusers?

Comment: [Here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/110649/6085) is one.

Comment: Every notion, but the first principles themselves.

Comment: @wythagoras: this question is really about the philosophy of mathematics; whether everything in math can be proved from first principles is not a "mathematical" question.

Comment: @Putin: the question as phrased seems philosophical and very broad. It could be made more focused by explaining what sort of "first principles" you mean. Do you mean the ordinary informal proof from first principles that is done all the time? Or formalized proof? In the latter case there is both the theory of formalized proof, and the practice using proof assistants such as Isabelle and Coq. All of this is too much for one question, but a small, focused part of it might work.

Answer (score 3):

Those first notions are often called axioms. What we can prove depends on the axiom system. However, Gödel's first incompleteness theorem states the following, quoting Wikipedia:

> Any effectively generated theory capable of expressing elementary arithmetic cannot be both consistent and complete.

Here we have two terms that might need some explanation:

- Consistent: We have no contradictions in the system. That means that there doesn't exist a proposition $\varphi$ such that we can prove both $\varphi$ and $\neg\varphi$.
- Complete: We can prove or disprove all propositions. That means that there doesn't exist a proposition $\varphi$ such that we can prove neither $\varphi$ nor $\neg\varphi$.
- Effectively generated theory: This means that there exists a computer program that can enumerate all the axioms of the system without listing expressions that are not axioms.
- Elementary arithmetic: I think [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic) gives a reasonable explanation.

Therefore, no, given a system of axioms that is consistent, we can not prove everything in maths form it. Now it is time for an example: In the currently accepted theory of set theory, ZFC, the continuum hypothesis is independent, that means that neither $\mathsf{CH}$ nor $\neg\mathsf{CH}$ can be proven form ZFC. You can read more on this on Wikipedia.

Comment: "effectively generated" also needs some explanation. As do "elementary arithmetic" and "expressing". Even "theory". Plus, then, you have to justify why you are equating mathematics with first-order formalizations. And why you are treating these matters in classical logic rather than some other more constructive setting.

Comment: That definition of elementary arithmetic is, let's say, fairly non-standard.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo How would you define it?

Comment: Primitive recursive arithmetic.